# What search box is this?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-box

I want to customize the WHMCS for domain search results.
Then customize the results to be shown in a lightbox state. 
I've seen it in [Iranserver](https://www.iranserver.com/), a hosting company.
What couldn't find something similar in codepen. Do you guys have any good code i could use that looks like this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like a nice idea, but what is the problem stopping you doing it? at the moment it's mostly a statement

Comment: WHMCS allows for ajax search box.
also in version 7 they made this ajax lookin - domain suggester that you could leverage. i don't know if you use this version or not. Do that then customize the searchbox by changing the css to your desired look.

Answer (score 0):

tnx, i've seen the domain suggester option but didn't use it.
i'm gonna check it out  in the portal search and see what happens.
regards

Answer (score 0):

They using custom coding. Means they fetch(Get) details from whmcs and list on php page . Then once client choose the domain , it directly "post" to whmcs .
WHMCS allow this facility .